# How to store and read session (value) in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I am having trouble in store and read sessioned data with `Angularjs` .
After click on button emp_name should store in `session` and also how can i read stored emp_name from `session` .

[Sample in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aX8A6b91obPO4aAr1XAF?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.employee = [{
      emp_id: 1,
      emp_name: 'Jes',
      emp_cont:9876543445
    }, {
      emp_id: 2,
      emp_name: 'Sandy',
      emp_cont:3553454345
    }, {
      emp_id: 3,
      emp_name: 'Alex',
      emp_cont:9343434345
    }, {
      emp_id: 4,
      emp_name: 'Nancy',
      emp_cont:9876543445
    }, {
      emp_id: 5,
      emp_name: 'Scott',
      emp_cont:9834564455
    }
  ];
  
          $scope.returnRefId = function (emp) {           
            try {
                  //  test emp
                  alert(emp);
                  // session code here
                  
            }
            catch (e) {
                  alert("some errror");
            }
        };
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style:none;float:left;padding:10px;border:1px solid #ddd;height:20px;width:100px}
ul{clear:both}
label{color:red}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="employees in employee | filter:customFilter">
    <li>{{employees.emp_id}} </li>
    <li>{{employees.emp_name}} </li>
    <li>{{employees.emp_cont}} </li>
    <li><button   ng-click="returnRefId(employees.emp_name);" >Add Session</button></li>    
  </ul>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <label id="read_ses">How to store and read emp_name thru only session</label>
</body>

</html>
```

I have created alert with emp_name on click by using `angularjs`. I want that on button click emp_name should store in `session` and for `session`testing purpose read sessioned emp_name data somewhere on page.

Any and all help/advice is sincerely appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your session storage code could look something like this using Javascript APIs for session storage. You will have to serialize your Javascript object as session storage only supports strings.

```
$scope.returnRefId = function (emp) {           
        try {
              //  test emp
              alert(emp);
              // session code here
              sessionStorage.setItem("emp-key", JSON.stringify(emp));
        }
        catch (e) {
              alert("some errror");
        }
 };
```

Alternatively, you can storage each property of `emp` in a separate storage key. Debugging should be as simple as

`sessionStorage.getItem("emp-key")`

More information on session storage can be found here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Also checkout ngStorage https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Hello Omkar.  I tried this but retun "null"  ..... `$scope.returnRefId = function (emp) {           
    try {
      //  test emp
     // alert(emp);
      // session code here
      sessionStorage.setItem("emp-key", JSON.stringify(emp));
      }
      catch (e) {
        alert("some errror");
      }
      var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
      alert(data);
   };`

Comment: The getItem method key should be the same as it was for setItem. In your case `emp-key`.

Comment: It should be `var data = sessionStorage.getItem('emp-key'); `.

Comment: thank you very much Omkar... this is what i was trying to do. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS applications are stateless, so there's no really a session. However, you can fake the session behaviour using the local storage. Here's the [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage),
a AngularJS module you can use to model you session.

In general, you create a service to access data contained in the local storage and then you inject the service whenever you need to access the session data.

Best!

Comment: same thing can be done by javascript , jquery, c# or any other scripting??

Comment: @Rakesh - since `localStorage` is HTML5 standard, yes. You can access it using pure javascript or through a framework like jQuery or AngularJS.
I'd suggest to use modules or plugins to manage it, since they generally provide some useful interface to avoid serialize/deserialize operation (considering that localStorage stores `Objects` as `String`).
About C#, it's generally executed server side so no, you cannot access the localStorage directly (but you can implement the logic to keep client and server data on sync).

Best!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP session is stored in server side and AngularJS works on client's side. If you want to access the HTTP session from Angular application, you will need to implement a service on server side ant then call it from Angular using httpService.