# Getting value from key session storage angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this value in session storage

```
tokenInfo : {
"token":"be802a56dbe1783262217a2066204701870ffb17",
"validUntil":"2017-10-24T09:56:53.000Z"
}
```

What i need is to get value of tokenInfo.token, quick and easy, hoe to do that in angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and read session (value) in AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130086/how-to-store-and-read-session-value-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the property as following:

```
let token = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('yourstoragename')).tokenInfo.token;
```

Comment: What is yourstoragename?

Comment: how you have stored , the name you used

Comment: like key and vlaue i dont have name?

Comment: then how did you store to sessionstorage?

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem('tokenInfo', JSON.stringify({ token: token, validUntil: validUntil}));

Comment: use whatever the value in this.storageKey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157275/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-miomir-dancevic).